# Get dynamically loaded assembly name in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, assemblies, system.reflection

I have a Silverlight 4 app that is allowing the user to upload a file, specifically an assembly.  Before the file is uploaded, I would like to verify that what they've selected is actually an assembly, and I would also like to get the full name of that assembly.  I'm getting a security exception when I try to use Assembly.Load(byte[]), is there a way to verify the assembly in Silverlight without actually loading the assembly?  Maybe a third party assembly information loaded?  Is there a reasonably simple way to examine the bytes in the byte array to determine this?

**Update**

The following pretty much shows me that opening the assembly is **not** a reasonably simple way to examine the byte array:
[**Common Language Infrastructure**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733AD403-90B2-4064-A81E-01035A7FE13C/MS%20Partition%20II.pdf)

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: This kind of validation is security sensitive and needs to be done server-side

Comment: This is the same comclusion that I've come to.  If you post an answer, I will select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of validation is security sensitive and needs to be done server-side

Answer (score 0):

you can use `AssemblyPart.Load()`, which won't let you load a byte[], but will let you load a stream.